# Pascal : function in paramater of another function/procedure

Tags: function, pascal

I didn't found anything on the net about this (maybe bad keywords). I'm trying to find a way to give in parameter a function in Pascal. For example :

`function foo1(arg1, arg2 : integer) : double;
begin
...
end;
function foo2(func : function, arg1 : integer) : double;
begin
    foo2 := foo1(arg1, 2);
end;`

And the call should be something like `foo2(foo1, arg1)`.
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "procedural types".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this :

`type TFunction = function (arg1, arg2 : integer) : integer;
function foo1(arg1, arg2 : integer) : integer;
begin
    foo1 := arg1 + arg2;
end;
function foo2(func : TFunction, arg1 : integer) : integer;
begin
    foo2 := func(arg1, 2) * 3;
end;`

The call should be something like `foo2(@foo1, 2)`

Comment: It's not evident from the question that the compiler is fpc, which "mode delphi" is only valid in. Anyway, you don't have to use it,  you can use '@' instead.

Comment: Didn't get where i should put the `@`. In `{@mode delphi}` ? before tfunction ? Should I delete `{$MODE DELPHI}` ?

Comment: If you don't want to use Mode Delphi, you can call foo2 with (@foo1, 2)

Comment: Perfectly what i was looking for. Editing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is posibble, and it's more simple than you think, there is no need to send a function as a parameter, every function/procedure that is declared can be used in another modules that are implemented after that declarations (the only exception is trying to call a procedure from a function, you can't do that).

I think this is what you want:

```
function foo1(arg1, arg2 : integer) : double;
begin
...
end;
function foo2(arg1 : integer) : double;
begin
    foo2 := foo1(arg1, 2);
end;

begin
...
foo2(2);
```

Becuase foo1 is declared before foo2, you can call it from foo2.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to make something like optparse in Python. In this module, you can add a Callback function on an argument. Something like `parser.add_option('-n', '--name', action='callback', callback=check_name)`. I want to do the same thing but in pascal, and i'm looking for a way to give function (like `check_name`) as parameter.

Comment: _«the only exception is trying to call a procedure from a function, you can't do that»_ this is wrong, no ?